# Installed .py scripts not showing up

Tags: python, add-on

Help a noob! I am hacking my way up the steep learning curve that is the Blender interface.

I'm using ver 2.75 on Mac.

I am trying to install an add-on called "Copy-And-Paste-UV-3.2"

I downloaded the .zip and went to the user settings panel/add-ons and clicked "install from file", and it put the .py file in the proper place under user/application support/Blender/scripts/addons. Went back to the add-ons panel and looked under "UV", but the new add-on wasn't there. Looked under the other tabs, but not there either. Hit refresh with no result. Restarted Blender with no result.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong to install this add-on script?
(my end goal is to transfer UV layouts across multiple identically shaped objects with different diffuse maps)

Thanx!

Comment: It could be that the addon just doesnt work, I had the same problem with another addon.

Comment: it shows up here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/urWmo.png  (don't let that path fool you, i'm using 2.75 )

Comment: What *Supported Level* is selected? Looks like it shows up under Testing looking at zeffi's screenshot.