# Troubleshooting when Addons don't show up

Tags: python, add-on, customization

There are often times when I install an addon (place the file/folder into my blender/2.XX/scripts/addons folder) and then it simply does not show up in the addons list within blender, so cannot be activated. Installing it from a file places it in the blender scripts folder in my app data folder (windows 7), but they still don't show up. These are addons that I know work for others, as I see them install them in tutorial videos or the like (.py, not patches or anything.)

So far, I have checked to make sure I am not filtering them out with the Support level filters.

What causes an addon to not be seen by the program, and what further troubleshooting steps I can take to get these working?

Comment: I don't agree with the reason for the close vote. The question is similar enough to existing ones. (related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36160/installed-py-scripts-not-showing-up?rq=1). A few things would help answer the question. 1) Which add-on (it helps to ask about a specific scenario, even if the answer can be generalized) 2) Do you have any messages about the addon if you start Blender from a commandline 3) Are you filtering with the correct Supported Level (there are three options just below the search feature on the Add-ons tab -- Official/Community/Testing)

Comment: It's one addon at the moment, but I've had this with several overall. I'm looking for a generalized list, not specifics for a given addon (as is the case for the linked question.) I have updated the question to clarify that I have checked my Supported level filters. I haven't tried running blender from a command line (It seems i need python installed? Not clear.) Is there another way to check for addon errors?

Comment: Here is the addon in question though: https://github.com/cheece/JiggleArmature

Comment: also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39745/addons-only-some-zips-will-install?rq=1

Comment: @zeffi picked it, it fails if you download the zip and tell blender to add the zip. unzip it and add the single JiggleArmature.py and it works.

Comment: @sambler, pretty frustrating stuff I imagine for new users / non scripters. _install from file_ could be more verbose.

Comment: Actually I'm thinking it could be more intelligent, does the unzipping create a folder containing `__init__.py`? no - only one .py file? let's use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addon which name (or folder name) contains  . (dot) cannot be loaded in Add-ons list. See [**this bug report**](https://developer.blender.org/T47651).

Take list below for example:

[image]

*Lens0.3* cannot be seen in Blender's Add-ons tab. And *MultiEdit2.5.py* cannot be sucessfully enabled even though it can be found in the list.

Solution would be to manually remove dots or replace with other valid characters.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no dots used in my particular file. There is a dash, but removing it hasn't helped. Neither has removing caps.

Comment: After seeing the addon, it can be solved by directly put the .py file in the addon directory, instead of nesting it in a folder.

Comment: I have and it still doesn't work. I've got it both in addons folder in the install location, and in the app data location, both in and out of the folder.

Comment: It does work. Assuming you are using Windows OS, then paste it to **.\scripts\addons** or **.\scripts\addon_contrib**. Or you can put it to **C:\Users\Your_Account_Name\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.7x\scripts\addons**.

Comment: I had it in both locations (folder and single.py), but it didn't show up. However, I then deleted it from both, re-unzipped it, and put it in. And now it shows up in either location. It's the exact same zip I had unzipped it from before, so this makes no sense at all. It should be the same file, and I've got it in the same place as before!

Comment: I have opened the new version I just unzipped, and checked the old version in my recycle bin. They are identical in text and file size.

Comment: You may check the MD5 of both files, which is more convincible. Sometimes Unzip softwares just fail due to unknown reasons, that's why they usually provide MD5 verification feature.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

If you go to `<user>/AppData/Roaming/blender foundation/blender/2.xx/scripts/addons` , you will find your installed addons for that version.

If some addons aren't showing up, then go to addons folder and modify somethings of that specific addon's file.

1. make sure that there aren't any periods (`.`), or symbols like that
2. make sure that if you open your specific addon's folder, you should directly reach to .py files.
   I mean , there should not be any extra folders between that path.