# "Modules installed", but nothing shows up

Tags: python

I decided to restructure this post, since I learned new stuff:

I wrote a script, which I want to use as an addon.
I wrote the necessary code for that and it works like a charm...

...until I want to install the .py

Installing works fine, since I can check for it in the scrips\addons dir. It just doesnt show up in the addons menu, where I need to tick the box to activate it.

I tried:

- removing dots and spaces from the .py name
- deleting and reinstalling it multiple times
- moving it in the dir manually
- changing the .py name to all sorts of stuff
- changing the "Version" in bl_info to all sorts of stuff

Code, containing the error:

```
#################################################
# Ive cut all the stuff you guys dont care about.
# The error must be in the remaining code
# since this still does not install
#################################################
bl_info = {
    "name" : "DOM Importer",
    "description" : "Import a STL file and do the DOM Stuff with it",
    "author" : "Alex",
    "version" : (1, 0, 0),
    "blender" : (2, 80, 0),
    "location" : "View3D",
    "warning" : "",
    "support" : "community",
    "doc_url" : "",
    "category" : "3D View"
}


import bpy, sys
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.types import Panel
from bpy.props import StringProperty, CollectionProperty
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ImportHelper
from pathlib import Path
from mathutils import Matrix
import math


class DI_OT_domimporter(Operator, ImportHelper):
    """ Import an STL and do things with it"""
    bl_idname = "import.domimporter"
    bl_label = "Import DOM as STL"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}

    filter_glob: StringProperty(
        default='*.stl',
        options={'HIDDEN'}
    )

    files: CollectionProperty(type=bpy.types.PropertyGroup)


    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.mode == "OBJECT"

    def execute(self, context):
        return {'FINISHED'}


class DI_PT_sidebar(Panel):
    """Display Process STL"""
    bl_label = "STL"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "DOM Importer"

    def draw(self, context):
        col = self.layout.column(align=True)
        prop = col.operator(DI_OT_domimporter.bl_idname)

classes = [
    DI_OT_domimporter,
    DI_PT_sidebar,
]

def register():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(c)

def unregister():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(c)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

Old Post:

I wrote an Script, which works fine (thanks to you all btw :D)

Now, I want to use it as an Addon. I have seemingly everything set up.

I have my bl_info and the register and unregister funcs. When I want to install the .py, it looks like its working. When I check my installed addons, however, it does not show up. Same is for the button I want to appear in the 3D View.

Opening the Console, I see the following:

```
    Modules Installed (my addon 1.0) from 'path\\my addon 1.0.py' into 'path\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\3.1\\scripts\\addons'
```

Which is indicating, it worked(?)

The baffling thing is, that it DID work some time ago, but idk what I did -.-

Using Windows, if its gonna be important.

Edit: I watched this Video and I think I did everything he did

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fr1HN0XgB58

Another Edit: Following this post:

[Troubleshooting when Addons don't show up](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55729/troubleshooting-when-addons-dont-show-up)

I substituted all dots in the file name (and spaces for good measure) with underscores. The post states, I am not allowed to use dots in the file name, which I hope excludes the .py^^?

Comment: This is usually a symptom of a problem with the `bl_info` but it is impossible to diagnose without looking at the script.  Can you paste the script into your question?

Comment: @MartyFouts I added the bl_info, hope it helps.

Comment: The 8 should be an 80, the 0 matters to Blender, but I don't think that's your problem. Is your script called '__init__.py'?  (Two underscore characters before and after "init".  Another thing to look at is to Window -> Toggle System Console and see if there are error messages on the system console.

Comment: Yeah we need to see the whole script, the whole file name etc. We can't debug just from the bl_info

Comment: @Jakemoyo I hope that helps. the whole file name changed alot, just because I was trying alot of stuff. I am pretty sure, its not the file names fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem was the inclusion of this key/value pair in the `bl_info` dict.

[image]

Whenever I get my bl_info i just copy it out of the *Templates > Python > Addon Add Object* file and fill it with my own info. Which you can see I did to test your script.

I found an old [article](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Addons/Guidelines/metainfo) in a Blender wiki that seemed to be written around 2.65 with the support key and it worked as well, but it seems like the order is important.

[image]

Probably has to do with Python dictionaries switching from arbitrary ordering to [strict ordering](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation) in Python 3.6